# How to detect hidden characters in string (for example zero width space) during debugging

Tags: c#, string

Is there any easy way how to detect (during debugging), that string contains some hidden character (for example zero width space)?

Example: During debugging I'm comparing two differnet strings and they seem equal to my eyes. Of course they differ in some hidden charaters. How to find the difference?

I used string.ToCharArray() method in "Immediate window" of Visual Studio but there must be more comfortable way.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this in the immediate window:

```
str.Contains("\u8203");
```

Or put it in the watch window so you'll just have to click the refresh button near the watched value to see the result, rather than re-entering it to the immediate (although you can always press up and then enter to re-enter the last command!)

To check for ANY hidden character, you can either have a static array with all hidden characters and check:

```
HIDDENS.Any(c => str.Contains(c.ToString())
```

And preferable even save the hidden characters as one-length strings and then do:

```
HIDDENS.Any(str.Contains)
```

OR you could be really sophisticated and do THIS:

```
private static readonly Bitmap BMP = new Bitmap(1000, 1000);
private static readonly Graphics GRAPHICS = Graphics.FromImage(BMP);
private static readonly Font FONT = new Font("Arial", 20);
private static readonly RectangleF RECT = new RectangleF(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

public static bool CheckInvisibleChars(string text)
{
    var stringFormat1 = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces);
    stringFormat1.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(
        Enumerable.Range(0, text.Length - 2).Select(i => new CharacterRange(i, 1)).ToArray());

    return GRAPHICS.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, FONT, RECT, stringFormat1).Any(
        reg => reg.GetBounds(GRAPHICS).Width.Equals(0f));
}
```

From here it should also be easy to return information about each hidden character, etc.

Comment: I probably didn't choose good title to my question (I've already renamed it). I mean how to detect any hidden character (not only "\u8203")

Comment: CheckInvisibleChars function is cool. Thanks! 

Btw. is there any GUI way which quickly "shows" invisible characters? I mean some editor or something like that.

Comment: You could just replace each char at an index of a zero-width rectangle with • or something, or with their ascii value between _underscore_

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
text.Contains("\u200B")
```

Or

```
text.IndexOf('\u200B') != -1
```

Comment: @Petr: Without any more information, that's not a helpful comment. Please give an *example* of where it doesn't work, or ask a new question.

Comment: @Petr it was not working because there was a mistake in the zero width space character reference. It should be specified in HEX format - **'\u200B'** and not as it was in DEC format - '\u8203'.

Answer (score 1):

For me works:

```
text.Contains((char)8203)
```

and

```
text.IndexOf((char)8203)
```