# Waiting for inputs to end and only then reading the textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, input

Basically, I want to make a constant input reader in my form, that waits for inputs and only after the input finishes(these inputs are from an external source, specifically - a hand-held scanner) should it be read, this code works exactly how I want, because the scanner at the end of input somehow informs that it's the end of stream/line(not really sure how though):

```
while (true)
{
    string someString = Console.ReadLine();
    doSomethingWithString(someString);
}
```

but I don't know how to cleanly transfer it to a form application.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Scanners (I believe) tend to send a carriage return (or similar) after each scan. Are you wanting to wait until you've received all scans and *only then* do something with the info?

Comment: Is the form application in a different project in a solution? because as far as I know you can't have the two of them in the same project.

Comment: Use System.IO.Stream instead of Console.ReadLine if you want to port this to a Forms app. You will need to figure out how the scanners terminate their input and write a class to manage communication with them.

Comment: @levelonehuman I want to wait for a single scan, and then do something with it.

Comment: @DominikH the console code is only there for refrence, i want to do the same that is in the code on a WFA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly, you want to do something like this:

```
public void SendScansToForm(string[] scans) //pass in an array (or list, or etc.) of the scanned items
{
    MyForm form = new MyForm(); //Create a new instance of the form
    form.variableToHoldScans = scans; //variable (on the form instance) to pass the scan to
}
```

In this way, you read in all the scans, then pass them into a new instance of the form. Presumably, this could be followed with a `form.Open()` or display the scans to the user, or change as needed to do whatever task is required.

EDIT:

Apparently I didn't understand; if you want to port the current code to forms, you can use `System.IO.Stream` (as mentioned in the comments). Additionally, you will need to determine *how* the scanner terminates an entry. This may be with a return character `\n`, `\r`, etc. or some other method and likely changes with different scanner models.

EDIT 2 - Additional info from the comments:

In order to read input from a scanner, you need to determine what character it's passing in to terminate the input. From my limited experience, this should be `carriage return`, `line feed`, `enter` or something similar.

Once this has been determined, it should be trivial to implement a method that acts on the presence of this character, allowing you to process each scan as they come in.

Comment: I don't think this is what was meant with "constant input reader". I would assume the form is open and also monitoring the console input stream continuously and do something with the input in the form every time something is coming in. But I could be wrong, maybe the OP could shed some light on this.

Comment: @FrankJ yea, I guess I didn't quite gather the intent of the question - hard to provide additional input on what's currently available; worst case, I'll delete the answer if it's too far off-base.

Comment: sadly, no, I actually want for the form(or an element in it) to wait for a full input(means until the scanner input stream ends) and then with the input(which is a single scan) do something with it. And to keep on doing this until I tell it otherwise.

Comment: @FrankJ you are correct. Though I'd say it's not necessary for it to stream through a console, I just put the code there for reference. I basically just want it to have the same functionality, rather than something like textChanged event with a timer that checks if the stream stopped and consider it a single input.

Comment: @jonasrudzionis what about using the `EnterKeyPressed` event or something similar? As I mentioned, I believe the scanner adds a `newline` (of some kind) after the scan, so if you know what the input terminator is, you can fire your event purely on the presence of this character

Comment: @jonasrudzionis Regardless, you'll need to know *what* the scanner is passing in after the regular input. When I used to work with scanners and excel, scanning in always moved to the column below (which is the equivalent of pressing the enter key).  Once you get this bit of information, it's trivial to execute code based on that condition.

Comment: @levelonehuman Got it, I'll have to test it out, thanks a lot! Any tips on how to actually figure out how it's actually ending the input?

Comment: @jonasrudzionis I can think of two primary means - debug the code and print out what gets scanned in to test for which character is at the end, OR look up the scanner model and see what info they have. Here is a decent answer on testing for 'hidden' characters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993069/how-to-detect-hidden-characters-in-string-for-example-zero-width-space-during

Comment: @levelonehuman thanks a lot! I'll mark this as the answer. You might want to edit it for people to read the comments. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @jonasrudzionis Happy to help - I'll add some of this info to the answer.